# Dúvida com retorno de dados Asp.net API

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Tenho um método que faz a inserção de registro, após ter inserido preciso retorno o id que foi gravado, mais não está retornando a informação. Agradeço a ajuda.

```
        [HttpGet]
    [Route("consulta/InseriUsuario/{apiKey}/{userKey}/{nomecompleto}/{email}/{login}/{senha}/{celular}/{cidade}/{uf}/{idperfil}/{idpais}/{ididioma}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage InseriUsuario(string apiKey, string userKey, string NOMECOMPLETO, string EMAIL, string LOGIN, string SENHA, string CELULAR, string CIDADE, string UF, int IDPERFIL, int IDPAIS, int IDIDIOMA )
    {

        try
        {
            var tTabela = new UsuarioAplicacao();
            tTabela.InseriUsuario(apiKey, userKey, NOMECOMPLETO, EMAIL, CELULAR, CIDADE, UF, LOGIN, SENHA, IDPERFIL, IDPAIS, IDIDIOMA );
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, tTabela.ToString());

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

```html
       public string InseriUsuario(string apiKey, string userKey, string NOMECOMPLETO, string EMAIL, string CELULAR, string CIDADE, string UF,  string LOGIN, string SENHA, int IDPERFIL, int IDPAIS, int IDIDIOMA )
        {
            var retorno = 0;
            var strQuery = "";

 //insert normal
                using (contexto = new Contexto())
                {
                    var reader = contexto.ExecutaComandoComRetorno(strQuery);
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        retorno = Convert.ToInt32(reader["IDUSUARIO"]);
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                strQuery = "select * from TB_USUARIO where IDUSUARIO = 0";
            }

            return retorno.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O método Inserir usuário, retorna uma string com o código que foi inserido. Você deve armazenar esse valor e depois retorná-lo na `Response`.

Tente assim:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("consulta/InseriUsuario/{apiKey}/{userKey}/{nomecompleto}/{email}/{login}/{senha}/{celular}/{cidade}/{uf}/{idperfil}/{idpais}/{ididioma}")]
public HttpResponseMessage InseriUsuario(string apiKey, string userKey, string NOMECOMPLETO, string EMAIL, string LOGIN, string SENHA, string CELULAR, string CIDADE, string UF, int IDPERFIL, int IDPAIS, int IDIDIOMA )
{
    try
    {
        var tTabela = new UsuarioAplicacao();
        string codigoInserido = tTabela.InseriUsuario(apiKey, userKey, NOMECOMPLETO, EMAIL, CELULAR, CIDADE, UF, LOGIN, SENHA, IDPERFIL, IDPAIS, IDIDIOMA );
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, codigoInserido);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Rovann, muito grato pela ajuda, deu certo, fiz o ajuste
 return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { usuario = codigoInserido } );

Answer (score 0):

No seu código 'InseriUsuario', me parece que está faltando o 'contexto.SaveChanges()' ou 'contexto.SaveChangesAsync()'.

Outra coisa, está retornando este método como 'string' - melhor alterar para retornar um 'int' que geralmente é o ID que acabou de ser criado e então usaria isso no 'Request.CreateResponse'.

Comment: Ronaldo, agradeço a ajuda, mais não e isso, mesmo que eu adicione um int ou  string, da no mesmo, eu não tenho um retorno da api,